# In-Series current source equation solving

Tags: analog, ltspice, current-source, electronic-load, calculus

I'm an electronic newbie, i was simulating this circuit on LtSpice and i found the result below, i tried with different methods (Kirchhoff's laws, Millman theorem, superposition) but i failed to have the right equation relating I to the other current source (amplitude is 0.00078 A) in function of the 3 capacitors. I can't doubt LTSpice results, so i assumed my calculations were wrong.

[image: Three in-series current sources with parallel capacitors]
[image: LTSpice output]
[image: Equation resolving]

Comment: Since these are steady-state sinusoidal sources I think you should try converting the capacitors to their equivalent impedance, then you should be able to use the node-voltage or mesh-current method to solve.

Comment: What are you after, exactly? Currents, voltages, for caps, for resistor? Your scan is very difficult to read, can you write, by hand, all the values for the amplitudes and phases? Otherwise the current I get is `I(C1): mag: 1.17705e-008  phase: 90°`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen i'm actually looking for the formula of the current passing through R1, that's it, not even the numerical value, just the formula using the other parameters in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it closely, you can see that one cell made of a current source and a capacitor acts as an integrator, with its Laplace expression \$\dfrac{1}{sC}\$. And you have three such cells on top of each other, which means they add up to one integrator with three times its magnitude, or \$\dfrac{3}{sC}\$. Adding one shunt resistor means the usual parallel operation:

$$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{3}{sC}}+\dfrac{1}{R}}=\dfrac{3R}{sRC+3}=\dfrac{1}{C}\dfrac{3}{s+\dfrac{3}{RC}}$$

And testing this shows identical traces -- here the magnitudes are slightly shifted, so that they don't completely overlap (their phases do):

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKNXgd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{a}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{c}=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{c}=\text{I}_\text{b}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{b}=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{a}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{c}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{c}=\text{I}_\text{b}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{b}=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ia == I1 + I4, I2 == I1 + I5, I3 == I2 + I6, Ic == I3 + I4, 
   Ic == Ib + I6, Ib == Ia + I5, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, 
   I2 == (V2 - V3)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (-Ib R2 - Ic R3 + Ia (R2 + R3 + R4))/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), 
  I2 -> (-Ia R1 - Ic R3 + Ib (R1 + R3 + R4))/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), 
  I3 -> (-Ia R1 - Ib R2 + Ic (R1 + R2 + R4))/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), 
  I4 -> (Ia R1 + Ib R2 + Ic R3)/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), I5 -> -Ia + Ib, 
  I6 -> -Ib + Ic, 
  V1 -> ((Ia R1 + Ib R2 + Ic R3) R4)/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), 
  V2 -> (-Ia R1 (R2 + R3) + (Ib R2 + Ic R3) (R1 + R4))/(
   R1 + R2 + R3 + R4), 
  V3 -> (R3 (-Ia R1 - Ib R2 + Ic (R1 + R2 + R4)))/(
   R1 + R2 + R3 + R4)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag4$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\tag6$$
- The current sources are given by:
  $$\text{i}_x=\mathscr{L}_t\left[\hat{\text{i}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f}t\right)\right]_{\left(s\right)}=\frac{2\pi\hat{\text{i}}\text{f}}{\text{s}^2+\left(2\pi\text{f}\right)^2}\tag7$$

So, we can solve for \$\text{I}_4\left(t\right)\$:

$$\text{I}_4\left(t\right)=\frac{58500000 \left(281 \pi  e^{-\frac{750000000000 t}{281}}+75000000000 \sin (10 \pi  t)-281 \pi  \cos (10 \pi  t)\right)}{5625000000000000000000+78961 \pi ^2}\tag8$$

Where I used the following code to find \$\text{I}_4\left(t\right)\$:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
Ia = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ib = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ic = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
R1 = 1/(s*C1);
R2 = 1/(s*C2);
R3 = 1/(s*C3);
R4 = 1;
C1 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C2 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C3 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[
  I4 /. FullSimplify[
     Solve[{Ia == I1 + I4, I2 == I1 + I5, I3 == I2 + I6, 
       Ic == I3 + I4, Ic == Ib + I6, Ib == Ia + I5, 
       I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, I2 == (V2 - V3)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, 
       I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2, V3}]][[1]], s, 
  t]]

Out[2]=(58500000 (281 E^(-750000000000 t/281) \[Pi] - 
   281 \[Pi] Cos[10 \[Pi] t] + 
   75000000000 Sin[10 \[Pi] t]))/(5625000000000000000000 + 
 78961 \[Pi]^2)
```

And I used the following code to find all the solutions (you only need to take the inverse Laplace transform of each solution):

```
In[3]:=Clear["Global`*"];
Ia = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ib = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ic = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
R1 = 1/(s*C1);
R2 = 1/(s*C2);
R3 = 1/(s*C3);
R4 = 1;
C1 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C2 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C3 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ia == I1 + I4, I2 == I1 + I5, I3 == I2 + I6, Ic == I3 + I4, 
   Ic == Ib + I6, Ib == Ia + I5, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, 
   I2 == (V2 - V3)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[3]={{I1 -> (10959 \[Pi] s)/(
   5000 (750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + s^2)), 
  I2 -> (10959 \[Pi] s)/(
   5000 (750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + s^2)), 
  I3 -> (10959 \[Pi] s)/(
   5000 (750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + s^2)), 
  I4 -> (5850000000 \[Pi])/((750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + 
      s^2)), I5 -> 0, I6 -> 0, 
  V1 -> (5850000000 \[Pi])/((750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + 
      s^2)), V2 -> (
   3900000000 \[Pi])/((750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + s^2)), 
  V3 -> (1950000000 \[Pi])/((750000000000 + 281 s) (100 \[Pi]^2 + 
      s^2))}}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response, i really appreciate the effort, as i mentioned above i was only looking for the formula of I4 using the other parameters, not a numerical application, your procedure to solve the problem was all clear until you decided to use LT, you got a linear equation for I4 `I4 = (Ia R1 + Ib R2 + Ic R3)/(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4)` and you obtained a solution for a differntial equation, it's not clear for me which equation was used to obtain that, again i'm just looking for  `I4 = f(Ia, Ib, Ic, C1, C2, C3)`.